# How to exclude same category dates near each other in R?

Tags: r, date

I'm working with a dateframe that consists of dates of events in different categories. My goal is to exclude dates in the same category that appear within 80 days compared to previous observation. For example:

```
observation Date       category

1           2015-05-05 green

2           2015-06-08 green #(this should be excluded)

3           2015-09-30 green

4           2014-06-30 red

5           2014-07-30 red    #(this should be excluded)

6           2014-09-30 red    #(this should not be excluded, since it is +80 days from the first obs.)

7           2013-01-01 blue

8           2013-02-01 blue   #(this should be excluded)

9           2013-06-01 blue
                     
10          2013-07-01 blue   #(this should be excluded)
```

I'm trying to exclude dates in the same category that appear within 80 days compared to previous observation (since in my study this is considered as same observation than the previous one). Yet I would want to spare observations that may appear within 80 days of observation that is excluded. Example of this would be observation 6 that would appear within of 80 days of observation 5 which should be excluded since it appears within 80 days of obs. 4 which is first obs. in that category. Hofefully you'll understand what I'm aiming for :D

I was thinking I could do this by group_by function and then calculating the differences in days between each observation in all gategories. Yet the problem would be that it would also exclude dates like observation 6 in my example.

I would greatly appreciate tips on how to do this the smartest way. I tried searching previous topics but couldn't find anything useful.

Regards
Aleksi

Edit: example of results with Merijn van Tilborgs code:

```
Date       Diff_days remove1 remove2
2015-06-29 119       FALSE FALSE
2015-07-09 7         FALSE TRUE
2015-07-15 6         FALSE TRUE
2015-08-18 34        FALSE TRUE
2015-10-03 46        FALSE TRUE
```

In this example the last observation should be saved since it has +80 days to the last oservation that is actually saved (2015-06-29).

Edit2: Iteration strategy proposed by benimwolfspelz: Code that I used to count days between every observation in the same category:
df2 <- df %>%

- 
- ```
  arrange(Date) %>%
  ```
- ```
            group_by(category) %>%
  ```
- ```
            mutate(diff_date = c(0,diff(Date)))
  ```

Comment: So, whether an observation should be excluded depends not only on its previous observation, right? Nr 6 is not to be excluded because Nr 5 is already and you want to do this in a "forward-in-time"-fashion, right? Maybe write a function that only excludes the first to-be-excluded observation, then apply it iteratively (`while`) until no Date-intervals of <80 are left.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm trying to do :) I'll try that.

Comment: So now I have managed to create a new column that has days between each observation in its own category. I suppose I could exclude second observations in each category that has less than 80 days but how on earth to I specify to code that i'm only looking second observation in each category.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that creates this new column?

Comment: It is now edited :)

Answer (score 0):

I expanded the test set a bit, but you have to test it in case I missed certain situations. Maybe it is possible to do it in one step, but I managed only to do it in two temporarily remove columns.

```
dt <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(16560, 16594, 16708, 16251, 
16281, 16343, 15706, 15737, 15857, 15887, 15888, 16252, 16617, 
16648), class = "Date"), category = c("green", "green", "green", 
"red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
"blue", "blue", "blue"), message = c(NA, "this should be excluded", 
NA, NA, "this should be excluded", "this should not be excluded", 
NA, "this should be excluded", NA, "this should be excluded", 
"this should be excluded", "this should not be excluded", "this should not be excluded", 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    Date = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_date", 
    "collector")), category = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), message = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"), class = c( 
"data.frame"))

library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)

dt[, remove1 := lead(Date) - lag(Date) > days(80) & Date - lag(Date) < days(80), by = category][is.na(remove1), remove1 := F]
dt[, remove2 := lag(remove1) == F & Date - lag(Date) < days(80), by = category][is.na(remove2), remove2 := F]

dt

#           Date category                     message remove1 remove2
#  1: 2015-05-05    green                        <NA>   FALSE   FALSE
#  2: 2015-06-08    green     this should be excluded    TRUE    TRUE
#  3: 2015-09-30    green                        <NA>   FALSE   FALSE
#  4: 2014-06-30      red                        <NA>   FALSE   FALSE
#  5: 2014-07-30      red     this should be excluded    TRUE    TRUE
#  6: 2014-09-30      red this should not be excluded   FALSE   FALSE
#  7: 2013-01-01     blue                        <NA>   FALSE   FALSE
#  8: 2013-02-01     blue     this should be excluded    TRUE    TRUE
#  9: 2013-06-01     blue                        <NA>   FALSE   FALSE
# 10: 2013-07-01     blue     this should be excluded   FALSE    TRUE
# 11: 2013-07-02     blue     this should be excluded    TRUE    TRUE
# 12: 2014-07-01     blue this should not be excluded   FALSE   FALSE
# 13: 2015-07-01     blue this should not be excluded   FALSE   FALSE
# 14: 2015-08-01     blue                        <NA>   FALSE    TRUE

dt[!(remove1 == T | remove2 == T)]

#          Date category                     message remove1 remove2
# 1: 2015-05-05    green                        <NA>   FALSE   FALSE
# 2: 2015-09-30    green                        <NA>   FALSE   FALSE
# 3: 2014-06-30      red                        <NA>   FALSE   FALSE
# 4: 2014-09-30      red this should not be excluded   FALSE   FALSE
# 5: 2013-01-01     blue                        <NA>   FALSE   FALSE
# 6: 2013-06-01     blue                        <NA>   FALSE   FALSE
# 7: 2014-07-01     blue this should not be excluded   FALSE   FALSE
# 8: 2015-07-01     blue this should not be excluded   FALSE   FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Code seems too advanced for my R-skills and I quite don't understand it but I decided to give it a try. Code seems to work fine with our example but when a run it with my dataframe I'll get me following error: "Error in days(80) : could not find function "days". Maybe something to do with Date datatype?

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to mention that it is part of the lubridate package

Comment: Now it worked when I ran it. Excellent job, thank you very much. I noted one systematic error in it when I checked my dateframe and it seems to appear when there are many observations in a short period of time. I posted an example of it to the original post.